# Add a different class to each item of a loop to build a masonry layout

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to add a different class to every item in the foreach loop

e.g

```
           <div class="tab-pane fade" id="albums">
                            <div class="card-columns">
                                @if (count($albums) > 0)
                                    @foreach($albums as $key => $album)
                                        <div class="card">
                                            <img src="{{$album->Cover_photo_url}}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                                            <div class="card-body">
                                                <h5 class="card-title">{{$album->Title}}</h5>
                                                <p class="card-text">{{$album->Description}}</p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    @endforeach
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Inside of this foreach each I would like every item with the class `card` to have an extra class added to it e.g
first item would just be `card` , second item would be would be `card p-3`, third item would be `card text-center` e.t.c

How would I go about doing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside your foreach you can get your loop index using `$loop->index` (starts from 0)

```
@foreach ($albums as $key => $album)
    <div class="card {{$loop->index == 1 ? 'p-3' : ($loop->index == 2 ? 'text-center' : '')}}">
         ...
    </div>
@endforeach
```

It's not the best option to use Ternary Operator, but it is possible, you can implement any logic you need, just use `$loop->index`

You can learn more about `$loop` variable in the [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#the-loop-variable)